# Bitbucket pipeline dynamic IP address and azure database restore

Tags: azure, .net-core, bitbucket-pipelines

I have CI deployment with dotnet core. Simply I need restore database, before publish to server. But azure firewall is blocking bitbucket engine dynamic IP address.

In yml config I have this:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script: # Modify the comma`nds below to build your repository.      
          - export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
          - export PROJECT_NAME=XXX
          - export TEST_NAME=XXXTests
          - dotnet restore $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet build
          - dotnet ef database update -p $XXX --configuration Release
          - dotnet test $XXXTests
#...
#...
```

After this pipeline is finished with error:

> Client with IP address 'DYNAMIC_GENERATED_IP_ADDRESS' is not allowed to access the
>   server.  To enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or
>   run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall
>   rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five
>   minutes for this change to take effect.

Is there way, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, although the Client IPs are dynamically generated, it should belong to one of the ranges mentioned [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html) (See the section *Valid IP addresses for Bitbucket Pipelines build environments*). Do note that these are prone to change as mentioned within, and that in addition to IP whitelisting, you should use a secure means of authentication for any services exposed to Bitbucket Pipelines.

And then you can whitelist them as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule#create-a-server-level-ip-firewall-rule), or [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-firewall-rule-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current).

Hope this helps!